# Can't get my wireless worked, it keep loading

Tags: wireless

I just have installed ubuntu 12.04 and the broadcom driver. When i try to connect to my wifi, it keep loading and asking for my password.

Comment: This sometimes happens when the driver is not correct for the device. Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device: lspci -nn | grep 0280 and also your driver: lsmod | grep -e wl -e b43 Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen on and off. Couple solutions should work unless you have a deeper problem.

1. Simple reboot should fix this.
   but that takes time, so a quicker way
2. Restart network manager in terminal `sudo service network-manger restart`
3. Or hover over the network indicator or the status bar until you get the dropdown. 
   Disable wireless, disable networking, then enable networking, enable wireless.

Comment: I think i have a deeper problem, it don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when this happens to me its because of a weak signal or a configuration problem. Try setting your wifi mode to an open network and testing if your wifi connects. If it works, then try different encryption methods or wifi types (abgn).